# How can I use amp cache?

Tags: amp-html

What is procedure to use AMP cache for my website? How can I enable my website to be served from amp cache? 
When the canonical url is used? If I want to serve the original page for desktop and amp page for mobile devices, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

I assume your desktop version (canonical) of the page is available in Google search results, if not then you need to submit a sitemap or notify Google of the presence of your canonical pages.

Then in your canonical pages you will need to provide a link to the AMPHTML version in the HTML head element, for example:

```
<head>
  <link rel="amphtml" href="...." />
  ...
</head>
```

Eventually the googlebot will see these headers and start indexing your AMP pages and providing them in Google search results for mobile devices only, but only if certain criteria are met, which I recommend you read the AMP documentation for further clarity.

Also use the AMP validator and https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/accelerated-mobile-pages for errors, warnings and indexing rate.

Also, don't forget to put the canonical URL in your AMP page too.